# How to get the latest value for the bucket in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of documents with just `count` field.

I'm trying to get the latest value for that field aggregated by date:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": "_timestamp",
  "aggs": {
    "result": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "_timestamp",
        "interval": "day",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "last_value": {
          "scripted_metric": {

            "params": {
              "_agg": {
                "last_value": 0
              }
            },
            "map_script": "_agg.last_value = doc['count'].value",
            "reduce_script": "return _aggs.last().last_value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem here is that documents fall into `last_value` aggregation not sorted by `_timestamp`, so I can't guarantee that the last value is really the last value.

So, my questions:

1. Is it possible to sort data by `_timestamp` when performing `last_value` aggregation?
2. Is there any better way to get the last value aggregated by day?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is possible to tune `scripted_metric` aggregations a little bit to solve the first part of the question (sorting by `_timestamp`):

```
"last_value": {
  "scripted_metric": {
    "params": {
      "_agg": {
        "value": 0,
        "timestamp": 0
      }
    },
    "map_script": "_agg.value = doc['count'].value; _agg.timestamp = doc['_timestamp'].value",
    "reduce_script": "value = 0; timestamp=0; for (a in _aggs) { if(a.timestamp > timestamp){ value = a.value; timestamp = a.timestamp} }; return value;"
  }
}
```

But I continue to doubt that this is the best way to solve that